# W2K8 R2 ApplicationPoolIdentity and gigs of data filling up drive

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, user-profile

I run an IIS7 web server and use `ApplicationPoolIdentity` with 'Load User Profile' and my primary hard drive is filling up fast.

The `C:\Users` directory is filling up with temporary data.

For example, `C:\Users\website1.com` and `C:\Users\website2.com` has a large amount of data.

Also `NTUSER.DAT{........}.regtrans-ms` and `NTUSER.DAT{........}.TM.blf`, as well as `UsrClass.dat{........}.regtrans-ms` and `UsrClass.dat{........}.TM.blf` are growing in size.

Is there a way I can safely clean these up?

Comment: Why Load User Profile? Presumably you're running an application that requires it? If so, what's it doing?

Comment: I assume that this is set to store temp data which would prompt me to question why you are not programmatically handling that data in a more robust way. Can you provide a little more info on what the application is actually doing?